# Create Dynamic checkbox angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

In my form I am having four checkboxes as default and having a textbox and add button.If I type the text in textbox and click Add button, I need to create a checkbox dynamically. The following code works fine but the dynamic checkbox is checked by default. How can I set the default value whether checked or unchecked?

```
    <div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-primary" *ngFor='let i of arrayofLevels' >
                                                                    <input id={{i.event_name}}  type="checkbox" value = {{i.event_name}}  (change)="checkAndCheck(i)" formControlName="event_name" ng-checked=false/>
                                                                    <label for={{i.event_name}}> {{i.event_name}}  </label> 
</div>
```

While clicking Add button, I am just pushing the new value to the arrayofLevels array.

```
arrayofLevels:eventDetails[] =[{event_id:1, event_name:"Form1"},{event_id:2, event_name:"Form2"}, {event_id:3, event_name:"Form3"}, {event_id:4, event_name:"Form4"}]

let newEvent = {event_id:resDataFilter.event_id, event_name:resDataFilter.event_name}
```

this.arrayofLevels.push(newEvent);

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `checked` state using one-way binding on the HTML `checked` attribute itself. You can bind the `checked` attribute of each checkbox to a collection (for example `checkedArray = [false,false,false,false]) that maintains the`checked`states. You can then manage and update the`checked` state of each checkbox externally using that collection.

Your template code would then be similar to `[attr.checked]=checkedArray[index]`. Note that the index is accessible when using ngFor. Update the Add button to include a new entry to the `checkedArray` for the corresponding newly added checkbox.